# Android: Check if NestedScrollView is at the bottom or at the top

Tags: android, nestedscrollview

I am using a NestedScrollView and I want to check if the NestedScrollView is at the bottom or at the top :-)

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37630070/1464013 It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
ViewCompat.canScrollVertically(target, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps check if [computeVerticalScrollOffset()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#computeVerticalScrollOffset()) is in [0,[computeVerticalScrollRange()/2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#computeVerticalScrollRange())]

Answer (score 0):

Create a SetOnScrollChangeListener

```
BottomSheet.SetOnScrollChangeListener(this);
```

The inside of the listener interface

```
  public void OnScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY)
    {
        if (scrollY == 0)
        {
            //Do something here when ur scroll reached the bottom by scrolling up
        }

        if (scrollY == (v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight()))
        {
            //Do something here when ur scroll reached top by scrolling down
        }
    }
```