# how to detect the position of the scroll nestedscrollview android at the bottom?

Tags: android, android-nestedscrollview

i just want to detect the position of the scroll nestedscrollview android at the bottom, and the to call function.
my code is :

```
scroll.getViewTreeObserver()
      .addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
           @Override
           public void onScrollChanged() {
               int totalHeight = scroll.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
               int scrollY = scroll.getScrollY();
               Log.v("position", "totalHeight=" + totalHeight + "scrollY=" + scrollY);
               if (scrollY==totalHeight) {
                   getPlaylistFromServer("more");
               }
           }
      });
```

but totalheight not same wit MAX ScrollY. how to fix it ?

Comment: Use `ViewCompat.canScrollVertically(View v, int direction)`

Comment: As *ViewCompat.canScrollVertically(View v, int direction)* is deprecated, use *View.canScrollVertically(int direction)*.

Answer (score 121):

Set `setOnScrollChangeListener` in a `NestedScrollView` params to get

- NestedScrollView v (parent with scroll)
- int scrollY
- int oldScrollY

To detect whether the offset is at the bottom, it is necessary to obtain the value of content height `v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight()` and compare the current scroll over the height of the parent, if you have the same value , it means that it has reached the end.

You can get the height with parent view with `v.getMeasuredHeight()`

```
NestedScrollView scroller = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myScroll);

if (scroller != null) {

    scroller.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

            if (scrollY > oldScrollY) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Scroll DOWN");
            }
            if (scrollY < oldScrollY) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Scroll UP");
            }

            if (scrollY == 0) {
                Log.i(TAG, "TOP SCROLL");
            }

           if (scrollY == ( v.getMeasuredHeight() - v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight() )) {
               Log.i(TAG, "BOTTOM SCROLL");
           }
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: How to check when the user stopped scrolling like once it becomes idle?

Comment: Would someone be able to explain why this line works? `if (scrollY == (v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight()))` How is it that the `NestedScrollView`'s measured height is smaller than the content's height, even though the `NestedScrollView` is the parent?

Comment: much better v.getMeasuredHeight() - v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight(, I change now

Comment: min API for this approach is 23, do you know another alternative?

Comment: @JoãoCarlos no this is not from 23 API. `setOnScrollChangeListener(View.OnScrollChangeListener)` needs API 23, but `setOnScrollChangeListener(NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener)` doesn't

Comment: You are the hero of my day, bro! Your answer helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: How to know the first element has been scrolled up ? Please help on this

Answer (score 45):

I know it's late but.. try this way.

```
scroll.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {
            View view = (View) scroll.getChildAt(scroll.getChildCount() - 1);

            int diff = (view.getBottom() - (scroll.getHeight() + scroll
                    .getScrollY()));

            if (diff == 0) {
                getPlaylistFromServer("more");
            }          
    }
});
```

Happy Coding..

Comment: Thank you. Its save my day.

Comment: If you have a recyclerview in nested scroll view. Please refer to this.

Comment: how to know user scrolled up first item ? Please help on this

Answer (score 8):

Webserveis answered right, but it needs a little bit of changes in onScrollChange (override method), like this:

```
if (scrollY === v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight()) {
   // end of the scroll view
}
```

Kotlin:

```
if (scrollY == v.getChildAt(0).measuredHeight - v.measuredHeight) {
    // end of the scroll view
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
  @Override
public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView nestedScrollView, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
    if (nestedScrollView.getChildAt(nestedScrollView.getChildCount() - 1) != null) {
        if ((scrollY >= (nestedScrollView.getChildAt(nestedScrollView.getChildCount() - 1).getMeasuredHeight() - nestedScrollView.getMeasuredHeight())) &&
                scrollY > oldScrollY) {
            LogsUtils.INSTANCE.makeLogD(">onScrollChange>", ">>BOTTOm");
        }

    }
}
```

Its worked for me,  [Source](https://medium.com/@mujtahidah/load-more-recyclerview-inside-nested-scroll-view-and-coordinator-layout-4f179dc01fd)

Comment: This one helped me

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me :

```
nestedScroll.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

            if (v.getChildAt(0).getBottom()<=(nestedScroll.getHeight()+scrollY)) {
                System.out.println("End of NestedScrollView");
            }

        }
    });
```

Basically , we add many views inside a nestedScrollView but wrap them together in a form of Single View. Therefore, childCount will always be 1 with its index 0. Thus, used `v.getChildAt(0).getBottom()` to determine its bottom. Now, `nestedScroll.getHeight()` returns height in pixel,and , `scrollY` will return current vertical origin. Therefore, the above condition will be true everytime the bottom of NestedScrollView is reached.

```
if (v.getChildAt(0).getBottom()==(nestedScroll.getHeight()+nestedScroll.getScrollY()))
```

This only works some time... therefore, don't use it in such way.

Answer (score 1):

I just changed a little codes of first answer to detect reaching end of recyclerview inside nested scrollview.

```
binding.nestedScroll.setOnScrollChangeListener(object:NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener {
        override fun onScrollChange(
            v: NestedScrollView,
            scrollX: Int,
            scrollY: Int,
            oldScrollX: Int,
            oldScrollY: Int
        ) {

        if (scrollY > oldScrollY) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Scroll DOWN");
        }
        if (scrollY < oldScrollY) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Scroll UP");
        }

        if (scrollY == 0) {
            Log.i("TAG", "TOP SCROLL");
        }
       
        if (v.getChildAt(0).getBottom() <= v.height + scrollY)
            {
            Log.i("TAG", "BOTTOM SCROLL IN Recyclerview.");

            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Last", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

for api <23 you can add a treeObserver.scrollChangeLister store a local float variable and check which way your scrolling like this

example

```
public class About extends AppCompatActivity implements 
ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener{

private float viewScrolled = 0;

   nestedScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onScrollChanged() {

    if (viewScrolled < nestedScrollView.getScrollY()){
        viewScrolled = nestedScrollView.getScrollY();
        Log.d(TAG, "scrolling up");
    }
    if (viewScrolled > nestedScrollView.getScrollY()){
        viewScrolled = nestedScrollView.getScrollY();
        Log.d(TAG, "scrolling down");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Webserveis answered right, but the condition should be like this

```
 if (scrollY == (v?.getChildAt(0)?.measuredHeight ?: 0) - (v?.measuredHeight ?: 0)) {
    //at bottom
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

```
            my_scroll_view.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {



                    if (scrollY == v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onScrollChange: SRCOLLED ==> scrollY: ======================================> THIS IS THE VERY END ");
                    }

                

            }
        });
```