# How to determine if a NestedScrollView is scrolled to the end and is idle?

Tags: android, scrollview, android-scrollview, nestedscrollview, android-nestedscrollview

Tried that :

```
NestedScrollView ns =(NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.nested_scroll);
        ns.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

            }
        });
```

But got stuck, does anyone have an idea?

Just to clearify what i want - i want to be able to observe the scroll state (as in addOnScrollListener of RecyclerView) and check only once, when the scrolling has ended (idle), if the user scrolled to the end of the NestedScrollView.

Comment: You helpful in SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143802/how-to-detect-the-position-of-the-scroll-nestedscrollview-android-at-the-bottom

Answer (score 20):

Unfortunately, `NestedScrollView` does not support implementation that dispatches scroll state, because it is totally different kind of Scroll view. Simply it is `FrameLayout` with `Scroller`.

Usually, end of a scroll view is reached when `ViewCompat.canScrollVertically (scrollView, -1)` returns false. For the scroll state you need to subclass `NestedScrollView` and add your own interface similar to the one of `RecyclerView`. Your interface method should be called in the following overriden methods:

`stopNestedScroll()` -> `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`

`startNestedScroll()` -> `SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING`

`dispatchNestedPreFling()` -> `SCROLL_STATE_FLINGING`

**Please don't forget to make the super calls of these methods. If you don't you will break NestedScrollView behavior**

**Edit:**

```
public class NestedScrollingView extends NestedScrollView {
    private int mState = RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;

    public interface NestedScrollViewScrollStateListener {
        void onNestedScrollViewStateChanged(int state);
    }


    public void setScrollListener(NestedScrollViewScrollStateListener scrollListener) {
        this.mScrollListener = scrollListener;
    }

    private NestedScrollViewScrollStateListener mScrollListener;

    public NestedScrollingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NestedScrollingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public NestedScrollingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void stopNestedScroll() {
        super.stopNestedScroll();
        dispatchScrollState(RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(View child, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
        dispatchScrollState(RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING);
        return super.onStartNestedScroll(child, target, nestedScrollAxes);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean startNestedScroll(int axes) {
        boolean superScroll = super.startNestedScroll(axes);
        dispatchScrollState(RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING);
        return superScroll;
    }


    private void dispatchScrollState(int state) {
        if (mScrollListener != null && mState != state) {
            mScrollListener.onNestedScrollViewStateChanged(state);
            mState = state;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How can I use this with `if` statement, i want to check if scrolling is IDLE then do something and when it's DRAGGING do something else..!?

Comment: stopNestedScroll is also called on MotionEvent.ACTION_UP event

Answer (score 13):

as I know the easiest way to do this is to use setOnScrollChangeListener of NestedScrollView :

```
 NestedScrollView nestedSV = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.nested_sync_scrollview);

    if (nestedSV != null) {

        nestedSV.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                String TAG = "nested_sync";
                if (scrollY > oldScrollY) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Scroll DOWN");
                }
                if (scrollY < oldScrollY) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Scroll UP");
                }

                if (scrollY == 0) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "TOP SCROLL");
                }

                if (scrollY == (v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight())) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "BOTTOM SCROLL");
                    if (!isRecyclerViewWaitingtoLaadData) //check for scroll down
                    {

                        if (!loadedAllItems) {
                            showUnSentData();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I set mine to start fetching data when the user scrolls 95% down the list. This mimics infinite scroll. Here's my if check `nestedScrollView.getScrollY() >= ((v.getMeasuredHeight() - nestedScrollView.getMeasuredHeight()) * 0.95)`