# How to check when NestedScrollView becomes idle or when it stopped

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

I have this layout

```
<FrameLayout>
    <NestedScrollingView>

        <LinearLayout>
               //some views 
        </LinearLayout>

        <RecyclerView/>

    </NestedScrollingView>
</Frame>
```

I want something to happen once the user stopped scrolling, and another thing
once he starts scrolling..!

**What I've tried:**

- I tried using `recyclerView.addOnScrollListener` with the help of the States, but this isn't allowed because of this `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)`
- I looked everywhere, but nothing on `NestedScrollView` expect **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37667686/7801361)** it seems there's a workaround, but I don't know how to apply the condition, I want to use `if` statement to check for `Idle` and `Dragging` states.!? any help with that!?
- This **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181828/android-detect-when-scrollview-stops-scrolling)** has a lot of greats solution for the problem but it's for `ScrollView` not nested, is there a solution that can be applied for the nested somehow..! I've read them but couldn't figure one.!

Comment: `NestedScrollView` Cannot have more than 1 direct child

Comment: why? and it's working fine with me, I only want to detect when the scrolling stops !

Comment: For me it gives `IllegalStateException`

Comment: I don't know, but it works fine with me, do you have an idea on how to detect when the nestedScrollView stops.

Comment: I don't think there is one specific listener for that... Try the touch listener and look for specific actions