# NestedScroll view detect scroll state

Tags: android, android-nestedscrollview

I am trying to detect scroll state whenever is it STATE_IDLE or DRAGGING. For the reference i found this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37667686/1108519

which has helped me to get the basic idea, i implemented it but its just detecting STATE_IDLE and forcing method

```
@Override
public void stopNestedScroll() {
    super.stopNestedScroll();
    dispatchScrollState(RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE);
}
```

other two methods onStartNestedScroll and startNestedScroll are never called, so because of checking state in dispatchScrollState i never get my method called where i extend interface.

The only additional thing i added is i extended my class with

```
NestedScrollingView.NestedScrollViewScrollStateListener
```

and set the scrollListener in this class as:

```
nestedScrollView.setScrollListener(this);
```

So what could be causing that its not calling start methods?