# Android / C# : Detect that NestedScrollView reached the bottom

Tags: c#, android, nestedscrollview

As titled, i am looking for an event that detects that the nestedscrollview reached the bottom of the layout.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143802/how-to-detect-the-position-of-the-scroll-nestedscrollview-android-at-the-bottom
Set OnScrollChangeListener to your NestedScrollView.

Comment: Are you using C# or Java?

Comment: @Nemus I use C#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to detect the position of the scroll nestedscrollview android at the bottom?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143802/how-to-detect-the-position-of-the-scroll-nestedscrollview-android-at-the-bottom)

Comment: @rishit_s thats what EugenUngurean suggested but i am looking for something better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my solution based on the links @EugenUngurean and @rishit_s commented. Thank you very much guys.

Basically i inherited IOnScrollChangeListener.

```
public class EventFragment : MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity<EventInfoViewModel>, IOnScrollChangeListener
```

Then create a NestedScrollView OnScrollListener and finished it with the interface of the listener. 
    BottomSheet.SetOnScrollChangeListener(this);

```
 public void OnScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY)
    {

       if (scrollY == (v.GetChildAt(0).MeasuredHeight - v.MeasuredHeight))
        {
            SwitchToEventInfo(true);

        }
        else if (scrollY == 0)
        {
            SwitchToEventInfo(false);
        }
    }
```