# Android: How to detect when NestedScrollView scrolled to the bottom

Tags: android, kotlin, android-scrollview

I have tried some approach and since we have different screen size, I am not able to get a better way. Here is my code

```
  private val scrollContainer
    get() = View.findViewById<NestedScrollView>(R.id.scroll_container)


 scrollContainer.setOnScrollChangeListener { _, _, newScrollY, _, oldScrollY ->
        val length = 1.5
        val deltaScrollY = newScrollY - oldScrollY
        if (deltaScrollY > length) {
            View.hide()
        }
        if (deltaScrollY < -length) {
            View.show()
        }
    }
```

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/37606211/10248593 may help you.

Comment: private fun setupScrollListener() {
        scrollContainer.setOnScrollChangeListener(NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener { view, _, scrollY, _, _ ->
            if (view.getChildAt(0).bottom <= scrollContainer.height + scrollY) {
                View.hide()
            }else{
                connectedDevicesCountBanner
        })
    }

I solved with this..

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem

```
    private fun setupScrollListener() {
    scrollContainer.setOnScrollChangeListener(NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener { view, _, scrollY, _, _ ->
        if (view.getChildAt(0).bottom <= scrollContainer.height + scrollY) {
           //at bottom
        }else{
          
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
scroll.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {
            View view = (View) scroll.getChildAt(scroll.getChildCount() - 1);
            int diff = (view.getBottom() - (scroll.getHeight() + scroll
                    .getScrollY()));

            if (diff == 0) {
              //your code  
            }          
    }
});
```